# Issue when compiling libmosquitto with TLS

Tags: gcc, makefile, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm working on libmosquitto library and having some trouble in setting up the TLS on the library on my mac.

When i'm compiling with TLS and TLS_PSK enabled i get an error "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64".

As i understand that the compiler should be g++ instead of default gcc in mac. (i could be wrong). If so, what changes do i need to make in the make file?

Can someone guide me how to generate libmosquitto files with TLS & TLS_PSK enabled on mac with 64 bot architecture?

Update: I got the application library to compile. The issue was with conflicts between xcode version.

I now have a different problem. When i'm using mosquitto_tls_set the entire function is skipped and responds with MOSQ_ERR_NOT_SUPPORTED.

Here a preprocessor value is being checked WITH_TLS. Where do i enable this in the code? I have already complied the source WITH_TLS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was that the preprocessor was not getting set when i was compiling the code from XCode (my IDE). I had to use preprocessor macro's to set the WITH_TLS flag and voila it worked.

Comment: I am also facing same problem, Can you please assist me with steps to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I'd be surprised if you need to use g++ instead of gcc.

Anyway, the correct solution is either to use `brew install mosquitto`, or use cmake to generate the Makefiles / XCode project files.

Comment: You are right, i didn't need g++. I was using XCode so i was not passing the preprocessor macros with was not setting the WITH_TLS Parameters.